# How to display data in gridview in laravel 5.2 or is there any crud generator in laravel by default not third party

Tags: php, laravel

Like in yii , we have gridview and listview. Is there any way to display data in table form and have pagination in laravel 5.2 . Please provide me any tutorial for this.

Comment: Laravel pagination - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Default laravel pagination.

```
But I would suggest to go for  Datatables(client side)+ https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle(serverside)
```

Ajax based

This package will manage all of your sorting and limiting the data pagewise.